# live streaming in iPhone

Tags: iphone, live-streaming

I ve an audio file in Server machine, how to stream it live to iPhone?
what is the concept or technology involved behind live streaming in  iPhone?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [MPMoviePlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/MPMoviePlayerController/MPMoviePlayerController.html) for streaming of your audio file, also take care of audio format, documentation says it supports only mp3,aac.

Comment: Can you be bit more elaborative, can HTTP live Streaming be an alternative for MPMoviePlayerController?

Comment: Then the question will be, how will you play the audio while its being downloaded.
See HTTP can help you to download the audio file from the server in chunks say for 10 MB audio file can be downloaded in 1MB per second part and also you can keep track that how much it is downloaded but as you have asked about live streaming then it should play the audio while it is being downloaded, that I guess will have performance issues if you play the audio in different thread.
So better to use MPMoviePlayerController which downloads and plays at the moment, though it doesn't save the file persistently.

Comment: Can i use MPMoviePlayerController to stream and play audio only, [not a video] in my application.

Comment: yes sure. documentation says "If you use this class to play audio files, it displays a white screen with a QuickTime logo while the audio plays. For audio files, this class supports AAC-LC audio at up to 48 kHz, and MP3 (MPEG-1 Audio Layer 3) up to 48 kHz, stereo audio."